# Java regex question with groups

Tags: java, regex

I want to be able to parse below strings with a single regex using groups? There may or may not be single/multiple whitespace between dash and numbers.

Input string examples:

```
"0.4 - 1.2 Mathematics"
"0.7-1.3 Physics"
"0.3-    0.7      Chemistry"
"4.5 Biology"
"2 Calculus"

group(1) -> lowGrade -> Float
group(2) -> highGrade -> Float (if exists)
group(3) -> class -> String
```

Can you help with the regex?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here is your working solution, if the "highGrade" is not available the second group is `NULL`.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String Text = "0.4 - 1.2 Mathematics";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^" + // Match the start of the string
                "(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)" + // Match the first float, the fraction is optional, (?:) is a non capturing group
                "(?:\\s*-\\s*" + // Match the whitespace and the - . This part including the following float is optional
                "(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?))?" + // Match the second float, because of the ? at the end this part is optional
            "\\s*(.*)" + // Match the whitespace after the numbers and put the rest of the chars in the last capturing group
            "$"); // Match the end of the string

        Matcher m = p.matcher(Text);

        if (m.matches()) {
            System.out.println(m.group(1));
            System.out.println(m.group(2));
            System.out.println(m.group(3));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String s = "Mathematics 0.4 - 1.2";

Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(.*?) *([0-9.]+) *(- *([0-9.]*))?").matcher(s);
if(m.matches()){
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
    System.out.println(m.group(2));
    System.out.println(m.group(4));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think you replied before I edited the question, I'm sorry, it's my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
String s = "Mathematics 0.4 - 1.2";
pattern = Pattern.compile("([^\d\.\s]+)\b\s+(\d+\.\d+)\D*(\d+\.\d+)?");
matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
if (matcher.matches()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(3));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think you replied before I edited the question, I'm sorry, it's my bad.